# Turning on/off WiFi

Tags: android, permissions, wifi

I have some question... 
I need to know is Wifi on my device enabled or disabled, so i check it with this code:

```
//check for internet connection
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
    if (!wifiEnabled)
    {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WiFi is disabled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and i need to add some permissions into manifest, and here i got an error, because `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"/>` is only for system programms....

so i ask you for help, how i can turn my app into system, or maybe i have been added some extra permission?

all permissions for Wifi i had added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: Note that your message "WiFi is disabled" should be "Wifi is enabled"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by your error message, I suggest to delete the UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS permission.